# Why are my results different to an identical example when I check for uppercase and lowercase characters?

Tags: r

I have a vector that contains several cities' names:

```
cities <- c("New York", "Paris", "London", "Tokyo", "Rio de Janeiro", "Cape Town")
```

I wrote a function to find the `minimum` and `maximum` letter of each city:

```
first_and_last <- function(name) {
  name <- gsub(" ", "", name)
  letters <- strsplit(name, split="")[[1]]
  c(first = min(letters), last = max(letters))
}
```

When I put `New York` and `cities` separately into the function `first_and_last`, I get the following results:

[image: myResult]

However, on a site that teaches R I have found a different set of results:

[image: anotherResult]

Why are the results different?

Comment: Ah, our codes are nearly the same, but our questions are not.

Comment: Running your code I get `first  last 
  "e"   "Y" ` for New York

Comment: same, can't reproduce your results. Try restarting your R session and try again.

Comment: The difference is probably due to locale settings. `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")` and `Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")` will give you the settings for your system.